# typescript throw TS7017 error with message when noImplicitAny is on: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature

Tags: typescript

[check demo on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20get(params%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%3Astring%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20url%20%3D%20''%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20paramStr%20%3D%20Object.keys(params).reduce((str%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20pairStr%20%3D%20%60%24%7Bkey%7D%3D%24%7Bparams%5Bkey%5D%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20str.indexOf('%3F')%20!%3D%3D%20-1%20%3F%20%60%26%24%7BpairStr%7D%60%20%3A%20%60%3F%24%7BpairStr%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20'')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20url%20%2B%3D%20paramStr%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(url)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20url%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

set option `noImplicitAny` to `true`, then the error thrown.

[image: noImplicitAny]

[image: error scrrenshot]
How to fix this without setting `noImplicitAny` to `false`.

Code:

```js
function get(params = {}):string {
    let url = '';

    const paramStr = Object.keys(params).reduce((str, key) => {
        const pairStr = `${key}=${params[key]}`;
        return str.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? `&${pairStr}` : `?${pairStr}`;
    }, '');

    url += paramStr;
    console.log(url);

    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can explicitly specify types:

```ts
function get(params: { [key: string]: any } = {}): string {
    let url = '';

    const paramStr = Object.keys(params).reduce((str, key) => {
        const pairStr = `${key}=${params[key]}`;
        return str.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? `&${pairStr}` : `?${pairStr}`;
    }, '');

    url += paramStr;
    console.log(url);

    return url;
}
```

**PS:** basically all similar problems can be solved by providing concrete types.

Comment: Thanks. This solve the problem. But I encounter an error: `TS2304: Cannot find name 'params'.` after doing this. How to solve this? :-)

Comment: @tjfdfs there should not be any errors, but anyway i removed the second type anotation. if you still have an error - please provide playground link with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because `params` does not have a type signature associated with it. You need to provide a signature that defines the type of the `key` and `value` pair in the dictionary.

You can do this like so:

```
function get(params: { [key: string]: string } = { }):string {
```

---

A more distinct example of this problem is:

```
const dict = {};
dict[5] = "five";
```

That will cause errors until you provide a type signature for `dict`:

```
const dict: { [key: number]: string } = {};
dict[5] = "five";
```